# Git sees duplicated modified file

Tags: git, git-add, git-status

In my repository there is a file (always that one) that always gives me trouble.
I'm working with coffeescript and generating the js with a grunt task.
For several times `git status` told me that this file was modified and needed to be added. The problem is that git sees this file **duplicated**:
[image]

Ok..so I try to add everything with `git add :/` and all the files are added, included ONE copy of `AreaChart.js` while the other one remains `modified` and unstaged. If I try to `checkout` or `add` it manually, nothing happens, its status remains `modified` and unstaged.

Is it a git bug? How can I fix this?

**EDIT**:
actually git sees the same file with 2 different file names, that is `AreaChart.js` and `Areachart.js`.
If I `ls` I only see `AreaChart.js` (uppercase C) as it is supposed to be.

**HINT:**
If I add `AreaChart.js` (uppercase `C`) --> git adds `Areachart.js` (lowercase `c`)
If I add `Areachart.js` (lowercase `c`) --> git adds `Areachart.js` (lowercase `c`)

**EDIT2**:

1. I found out the both files exist on the repository
2. To my surprise I've found out that my filesystem (mac) is not case-sensitive, so if I `touch test` and `touch Test` only one file is created (or maybe both but I can see only one of them)
3. The output `git config core.ignorecase` says `true`

Comment: Those filenames are actually different: the second has a lower-case 'c'. Are you , or is some other developer, working on Windows?

Comment: Can you try a `git add -A :/` That could record an addition *and* a deletion, to take into account a possible case change during the generation.

Comment: @Chris you are right, but a `ls` inside the directory tells me that only one exists, the one with uppercase C:  `AreaChart.js` as it supposed to be, so it is git that sees 2 files!

Comment: I've made an edit about the two filenames and the changing `c`

Comment: @Leonardo, if you're on Windows you may only see one file even if both exist. The underlying NTFS filesystem is case-sensitive, but Windows itself is not. This can lead to weirdness like you're experiencing.

Comment: @Chris nope, I'm on a mac

Comment: What's the output of `git config core.ignorecase`?

Comment: @EdwardThomson the result of this command is `true`! Also, with my immense surprise I've found out that my fs is NOT case-sensitive, if I `touch hello` and `touch Hello` only one file is created

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look again carefully

```
AreaChart.js
```

and

```
Areachart.js
```

are different files. One has capital C and other has lower case c character.

Since Git is case sensitive, and your filesystem is case *insensitive*, you will only see one of these on your filesystem.  If you only want one in Git, you should remove the other, with `git rm --cached Areachart.js`, and make sure that your updates are added via `git add AreaChart.js`.

Comment: Is your repo on github? If so I can try by downloading it.

Comment: @Leonardo I'm not sure what you're saying "nope" to.  Did you try this?  If you only want one in your repository, you need to delete the other (`git rm --cached Areachart.js`, for example)

Comment: @EdwardThomson `git rm --cached Areachart.js` fixed the problem but again, `ls -a` showed me only one existing file, the one with the uppercase. Could you put this as an answer?

Comment: Also suppose you make two files add to git. Then delete one from filesystem. Git will show you 2 files but your filesystem just 1 unless you remove it from git also or checkout from from got to get it back. Something similar might have occurred in your case by chance

Comment: ok, this is still not the solution, sorry..I have tried to modify again the original `AreaChart.coffee`, then after compiling it git keeps on seeing (randomly) sometimes the the two different js files, sometimes only one (correct) file. Again, in my file system I only have One of them `AreaChart.js`

Comment: @Leonardo Are you specifying the case correctly for all your operations?  What do you mean "git keeps on seeing" these files?  Untracked or staged?  If the latter, how did you run `git add`?

Comment: @EdwardThomson git tells me that those two files are modified (tracked). One of them actually exists phisically, the other one doesn't exists on my file systems

Comment: How did those changes get staged?  Did you run `git add`?  Or is something else doing it for you?  If so, what's that other thing?

Comment: @EdwardThomson please read the Hint on my question, I can't get them both staged, only one. I'm seriously thinking it is a filesystem case-sensitive problem. Now I'm not on the faulty mac, I'll check again tomorrow

Answer (score 3):

Get gets confused when it's on case-insensitive file systems. Try:

```
git mv --force Areachart.js AreaChart.js
```

Comment: a mac is supposed to be unix-like case sensitive, isn't it?

Comment: Nope, sadly not by default

Comment: You can run `git ls-files` to see both files if the OS doesn't show you